# How do I fill a DataSet or a DataTable from a LINQ Stored procedure?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I’m trying to fill data table from the sp. but it’s seems not right. Any ideas about my approach

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
     Using EdSQL As New MyEntities
       Dim Query = From St In EdSQL.MySp(Prameter).AsEnumerable
            Select St
            dt=Query.......
     End Using
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: dt=Query????? Problem comes with here. can not assign query in to data table. even .CopyToDataTable property does not popping up

Comment: Is gvStockEDI is your gridview?

Comment: Sorry. i have edited. no more grids

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this...

```
Dim EdSQL As New My Entities

Dim query = From st In EdSQL.MySp(Parameter).AsEnumerable
            Select St

gvStockEDI.DataSource = query.ToList()
gvStockEDI.DataBind()
```

Comment: Tx, I need to get rid of grids that’s the main objective of code

Comment: In that case use dt = query.ToList() instead of the last two lines. Of course you will need the Dim dt as New DataTable at beginning.

Comment: Its trowing error : Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List()' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.DataTable'.

Comment: Check this out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502850/linq-query-to-datatable-datasource

Comment: It seems you will need to add columns to your datatable and then you will be able to use dt = query.copytodatatable